# How to detect when a user logged in via a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, authentication, uiwebview

I want to have present a `UIWebView` with a login screen for a user to login to a service, and once they are properly logged in, I want to scrape the page for content. How do I figure out when they logged in to the service?

I know I could check the current `URL`, as it redirects to a specific, easy to identify `URL`, but at the same time, if they somehow navigated around the web until they came across this link and clicked on it, it would have unexpected results in my app.

Comment: One way could be send a separate request to server for login verification before opening the UIWebView,

Comment: Are there any tutorials on doing this in Objective-C? I'm confused how I'd do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to send request to the server, you could use some open APIs like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) (might be outdated) and [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). If you want to use Apple provided API then you can use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Basically you send `synchronous` request in your case.

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *reply = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

check the response from the server if user is logged in then open the `UIWebView`  with desired contents otherwise show error or alert.

```
if([reply isEqualToString:@"OK"]){
 // open and show Contents in `UIWebView`
} else {
 //show error not authenticated
}
```

[Here is some basic tutorial if you getting started.](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)

[One more tutorial for NSURLConnection](http://nscookbook.com/2012/12/ios-programming-recipe-4-using-nsurlconnection/)

Comment: I'm rather new to networking, how would I check the response to see if they logged in? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: you can send the response from the server for examaple `OK` in case user is authenticated otherwise some other string.

Comment: You can see my updated answer, I have provided some tutorials for NSURLConnection.

Comment: Oh wow, those helped a lot, thank you. In the example I want to use, with Instapaper, (http://www.instapaper.com/user/login) would it be sending a GET or POST request on login?

Comment: It depends on your demands, but try using POST as you might need to send the login details.